# .msg to .eml file using Aspose.Email missing Calendar data

Tags: c#, .net, outlook, aspose, eml

I am trying to convert from `.msg` to `.eml` file format using [*Aspose.Email for .NET*](http://www.aspose.com/products/email/net). Pretty trivial:

```
var msg = MapiMessage.FromFile(@"example.msg");
MailMessageInterpretor mmi = MailMessageInterpretorFactory.Instance.GetIntepretor(msg.MessageClass);
MailMessage eml = mmi.Interpret(msg);
eml.Save(@"example.eml");
```

If its a calendar invite, I see it in the `.msg` file and also in the `.eml` file, as shown below (`.msg` on top, `.eml` on the bottom):

[image]

It also includes the meeting `.ics` file within the `.eml` it produces:

> Content-Type: text/calendar; method="REQUEST"; name="meeting.ics";
>   charset="utf-8" Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64

However, the **problem** is that if it is a **meeting cancellation** instead of an invitation:

[image]

The resulting `.eml` as you can see, does **not** include meeting details, nor does the resulting `.eml` contain any trace of a meeting `.ics` (which **does** exist in the `.msg`). I can parse the `.msg` for it easily:

```
MapiCalendar calendar = (MapiCalendar)msg.ToMapiMessageItem();
```

Why is it not base-64 encoding the `.ics` for cancellations in the resulting `.eml`? Am I doing something wrong? Is it an Aspose bug? Is it normal behavior? What's going on here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you please share your input/output files with us on [Aspose.Email forum](http://www.aspose.com/community/forums/aspose.email-product-family/188/showforum.aspx)? We need to understand what steps are you taking that gives raise to this issue and will further assist you in the forum. If we find it to be a bug with the API, we'll log it for investigation by our Product team.

I work with Aspose as Developer Evangelist.

**Edit**:

Please try `mmi.InterpretAsTnef(msg)`. Though it should work with Interpret as well, but it seems an issue with the API. We're investigating the problem at our end, however, you can use the InterpretAsTnef meanwhile. You may register on www.Aspose.com free of cost. Our basic support is free for all whether it is paid or non-paid users.

Comment: Sorry but I don't have an account on the forum. However, the reproduction steps are quite simple. **1.** Send someone a meeting request on Exchange. **2.** Send that person a meeting cancellation on Exchange. **3.** Have that person save the meeting cancellation email (double click the email in Exchange, go to File, then Save As and it will save to `.msg` format). **4.** Use my code above on the `.msg` file to convert it to `.eml` and you will see it does not preserve the calendar cancellation (tested this on the latest version of *Aspose.Email* from *NuGet*).

Comment: Please try InterpretAsTnef. Though it should work with Interpret as well, but it seems an issue with the API. We're investigating the problem at our end, however, you can use the InterpretAsTnef meanwhile.

You may register on www.Aspose.com free of cost. Our basic support is free for all whether it is paid or non-paid users.